# spring program - BeanDefinitionStoreException after launching

Tags: java, spring, exception

I tried to write easy spring program.

And after lunching I caught next error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at spring.TestSpring.main(TestSpring.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 7 more
```

Here is code of this files:

```
public class HelloSpring {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String aMessage) {
        message = aMessage;
    }

    public void getMessage() {
        System.out.println("Your message: " + message);
    }
}


import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestSpring {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml"); 
        HelloSpring helloSpring = (HelloSpring) context.getBean("helloSpring");
        helloSpring.getMessage();
    }
}
```

And content of `Beans.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="helloSpring" class="spring.HelloSpring">
        <property name="message" value="Welcome to the World of spring!" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Structure of the program is into `src` - both classes + xml file.

I coudn't find why this happen?

**Edit:**

I downloaded, unzipped and added to project path next `jar` files [Commons Logging 1.1.3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi).

After launching I caught next message:

```
жовт 17, 2013 12:24:39 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@15ed659: startup date [Thu Oct 17 12:24:39 EEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
жовт 17, 2013 12:24:39 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at spring.TestSpring.main(TestSpring.java:8)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 13 more
```

Directory struckture is next:

```
spring_project
          src
             spring
                   Beans.xml
                   HelloSpring.java
                   TestSpring.java
```

**Edit2:**

I moved `Bean.xml` one level hiere to `src` level.
And now output is:

```
жовт 17, 2013 2:07:01 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@15ed659: startup date [Thu Oct 17 14:07:01 EEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
жовт 17, 2013 2:07:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
жовт 17, 2013 2:07:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@178f2b: defining beans [helloSpring]; root of factory hierarchy
Your message: Welcome to the World of spring!
```

Why this info message is emerged?

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: You missed the required jar file.Try download the jar from the link given and add to your buildpath and try:http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi

Comment: Or better yet, use Maven and let it handle the classpath for you.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I downloaded and added to project path but it keep throwing the same exception.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Can I solve this without `Maven`?

Comment: @nazar_art Yes. You can. That is what the process I said in my first comment. After you added the jar, Still facing the same issue ? where you ar egetting this error ? IDE or on Tomcat ? Jboss ?

Comment: @nazar_art That is another question. Clearly I don't have any Idea cause I'm not spring guy. Sorry  :(.

Comment: The problem is really with the location of Beans.xml. Error is clear and it is saying the configuration file is not in classpath. You have said both the source file and xml file are under source folder. Are you using any ide to build the application?

Comment: Show your directory structure.